# Communication between visitor and visitee

Tags: language-agnostic, visitor-pattern

My current project contains a complex object hierarchy. The following structure is a simplified example of this hierarchy for demonstration purposes:

> - Library
>
>   - Category "Fiction"
>
>     - Category "Science Fiction"
>
>       - Book A *(Each book contains pages, not displayed here)*
>       - Book B
>     - Category "Crime"
>
>       - Book C
>   - Category "Non-fiction"
>
>     - (Many subcategories)

Now, I want to avoid having nested loops all over my code whenever I need some information from the data structure, because when the structure changes I'd have to update all the loops.

So I plan on using the visitor pattern, which seems to give me the flexibility I need. It would look something like this:

```cs
class Library
{
    void Accept(ILibraryVisitor visitor)
    {
        IterateCategories(this.categories, visitor);
    }

    void IterateCategories(
        IEnumerable<Category> categorySequence,
        ILibraryVisitor visitor)
    {
        foreach (var category in categorySequence)
        {
            visitor.VisitCategory(category.Name);

            IterateCategories(category.Subcategories, visitor);

            foreach (var book in category.Books)
            {
                // Could also pass in a book instance, not sure about that yet...
                visitor.VisitBook(book.Title, book.Author, book.PublishingDate);

                foreach (var page in book.Pages)
                {
                    visitor.VisitPage(page.Number, page.Content);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

interface ILibraryVisitor
{
    void VisitCategory(string name);

    void VisitBook(string title, string author, DateTime publishingDate);

    void VisitPage(int pageNumber, string content);
}
```

I'm already seeing some possible problems though, so I'm hoping you can give me some advice.

#### Question 1

If I wanted to create a list of book titles prefixed by the (sub)categories it belongs to (e.g. *Fiction » Science Fiction » Book A*), a simple visitor implementation would appear to do the trick:

```cs
// LibraryVisitor is a base implementation with no-op methods
class BookListingVisitor : LibraryVisitor
{
    private Stack<string> categoryStack = new Stack<string>();

    void VisitCategory(string name)
    {
        this.categoryStack.Push(name);
    }

    // Other methods
}
```

Here I have already run into a problem: I have no clue on when to pop the stack, because I don't know when a category ends. Is it a common approach to split up the VisitCategory method into two methods, like below?

```cs
interface ILibraryVisitor
{
    void VisitCategoryStart(string name);

    void VisitCategoryEnd();

    // Other methods
}
```

Or are there other ways of dealing with structures like this, which have a clear scope with a start and end?

#### Question 2

Suppose I only want to list the books that were published in 1982. A decorator visitor would separate the filtering from the listing logic:

```cs
class BooksPublishedIn1982 : LibraryVisitor
{
    private ILibraryVisitor visitor;

    public BooksPublishedIn1982(ILibraryVisitor visitor)
    {
        this.visitor = visitor;
    }

    void VisitBook(string title, string author, DateTime publishingDate)
    {
        if (publishingDate.Year == 1982)
        {
            this.visitor.VisitBook(string title, string author, publishingDate);
        }
    }

    // Other methods that simply delegate to this.visitor
}
```

The problem here is that VisitPage will still be called for books that are not published in 1982. So the decorator somehow needs to communicate with the visited object:

> Visitor: *'Hey, this book isn't from 1982, so please don't tell me anything about it.'*
>     Library: *'Oh ok, then I won't show you its pages.'*

The visit methods currently return void. I could change it to return a boolean which indicates whether to visit sub-items, but that feels kind of dirty. Are there common practices for letting the visitee know that it should skip certain items? Or perhaps I should look into a different design pattern?

P.S. If you think these should be two separate questions, just let me know and I'll be happy to split them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Visitor pattern, as described by the GoF book, deals with *class* hierarchies and not with *object* hierarchies. To put it simply, adding a new Visitor type acts like adding a new virtual function to the base class and all the children, without touching their code.

The machinery of a Visitor consists of one `Visitor::Visit` function per class in the hierarchy, and the `Accept` function in the parent class and in all the descendants. It works by calling `Accept(visitor)` through a parent class reference. The implementation of `Accept` in the object that happens to be referenced calls the right kind of `Visitor::Visit(this)`. It is all fully orthogonal to any *object* hierarchy that may exist between instances of different subclasses of our root class.

In your case, the `ILibraryVisitor` interface would have a `VisitLibrary(Library)` method, a `VisitCategory(Category)` method, a `VisitBook(Book)` method, and so on, while each of `Library`, `Category`, `Book` and so on would inherit a common base class and reimplement its `Accept(ILibraryVisitor)` method.

So far so good. But from this point on your implementation seems to get a bit disoriented. A Visitor does not call its own Visit functions! Members of the hierarchy do, Visitor implements these functions for their benefit. So how do we go down the category tree?

Remember that to call `Accept(FooVisitor)` replaces the method `Foo` in the root of the hierarchy, and `FooVisitor::VisitBar` replaces the implementation of `bar::Foo` . When we want to do something with an object, we call its methods. don't we? So let's do it (in pseudocode).

```
class LibraryVisitor : ILibraryVisitor
{
  IterateChildren (List<ILibraryObject> objects) {
    foreach obj in objects {
      obj.Accept(this);
    }
  }
  IterateSubcategories (Category cat) {
    stack.push (cat);                 # we need a stack here to build a path
    IterateChildren (cat.children);   # both books and subcategories
    stack.pop();
  }
  VisitLibrary (Library) = abstract
  VisitCategory (Category) = abstract
  VisitBook (page) = abstract
  VisitPage (Page) = abstract
}

class MyLibraryVisitor : LibraryVisitor {
  VisitLibrary (Library l ) { ... IterateChildren (categories) ... }
  VisitCategory (Category c) = { ... IterateSubcategories (c) ... }
  VisitBook (Book) = { ... IterateChildren (pages) ... }
  VisitPage (Page) = { ... no children here, end of walk ... }
}
```

Note the ping-pong action between `Visit` and `Accept`. `Visitor` calls `Accept` on the children of the current visitee, the children call `Visitor::Visit` back, and Visitor calls `Accept` on *their* children etc.

This is how your second question is answered:

class BooksPublishedIn1982 : LibraryVisitor
   {
     VisitBook (Book b) {
       if b.publishedIn (1982) {
         IterateChildren(b.pages)
       }
     }
   }

Once again, it is apparent that the tree walk and the visitor machinery have just about nothing to do with each other.

I have left the decision of iterating or not iterating children entirely with each `Visit` implementation. This need not be the case, you can easily split each `VisitXYZ` into two functions, `VisitXYZProper` and `VisitXYZChildren`. By default, `VisitXYZ` will call both and each concrete visitor may override that decision.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I was trying to hide the tree walk from the visitor, because it shouldn't have to know about the inner structure of Library IMO. But you're letting it leak into the visitor, which goes against my gut feeling, but it does seem to solve both of my problems! So I guess I'll go with that, or something like it. In my search for an answer I came across [this Hierarchical Visitor Pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?HierarchicalVisitorPattern), which would also work for me, but only adds more complexity to the mix. I like your way better :)

Comment: By the way, where did my visitor call its own Visit methods? Because I sure didn't mean to do that! I realize that, to fully comply with the pattern, I'd have to call Accept on Category, Book etc. instead of directly calling VisitCategory and VisitBook from within the Library root. But I was trying to keep the example concise, it's long enough as it is right now ;)

Comment: A Visitor is a piece of functionality injected into the visitee type hierarchy, so I don't see much harm in the Visitor knowing a bit about the visitee structure. It could be possible to isolate this knowledge but I have to think about it more. As for your second comment, I have probably misread your Question 2 code, which does have a Visit method call another Visit method, maybe in a different visitor but still it is a bit suspicious.